# Tool to determine what the Python worker processes are doing?

Tags: python, performance-analysis, debugging, django

I have a django wsgi application running on Apache on Linux.

I would like to get an overview of what is going on during an average day.

Some months ago I wrote a tool to see what the python interpreter is doing all day long: https://github.com/guettli/live-trace

It has a major draw-back: If the python interpreter is inside the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), then no logging of stacktraces happen. This means the result is wrong.

Is there a different tool which helps me to see in which python source code lines the interpreter is most of the time?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/uber/pyflame

from the README

> A Ptracing Profiler For Python
>
> Pyflame is a high performance profiling tool that generates flame
>   graphs for Python. Pyflame is implemented in C++, and uses the Linux
>   ptrace(2) system call to collect profiling information. It can take
>   snapshots of the Python call stack without explicit instrumentation,
>   meaning you can profile a program without modifying its source code.
>   Pyflame is capable of profiling embedded Python interpreters like
>   uWSGI. It fully supports profiling multi-threaded Python programs.
>
> Pyflame usually introduces significantly less overhead than the
>   builtin profile (or cProfile) modules, and emits richer profiling
>   data. The profiling overhead is low enough that you can use it to
>   profile live processes in production.